# In what ways can I get the Group Hug achievement with the New Heroes DLC?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-defenders

The achievement **Group Hug** reads `Raised a Hero of each type to Level 70`. After the game released on Steam, they released the New Heroes DLC, which gives you access to gender-swapped versions of the original 4 classes who have different activated abilities.

This is a table showing which of the New Heroes are equivalent to the originals:

```
 Original     New Heroes DLC

  Squire         Countess
   Monk          Initiate
 Apprentice       Adept
 Huntress         Hunter
```

With that in mind, I need to know if I only get **Group Hug** for leveling the original 4 classes to 70, or can I mix and match for example, a Squire, Initiate, Apprentice and Huntress and still get the achievement? Or would I have to use all 4 from either the original group or the New Heroes DLC, by which I mean *either* leveling the Squire/Monk/Apprentice/Huntress *or* Countess/Initiate/Adept/Hunter together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Group Hug achievement only works with the original four heroes.

Comment: As of [patch 7.16](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?30004), the `'Group Hug' Achievement can now optionally be earned using the corresponding Gender-Swapped Heroes`. I would posit to say that you still can't mix and match the heroes for the achievement, but Countess/Initiate/Adept/Hunter should now be possible.